# Pipe within a function in R

Tags: r

I've been trying to make my function work but all the suggestions from other posts with similar issues have not worked.

The following is my function:

```
tab_mw_y_z <- function(dta, x, y, z, weight){
  dta_sub <- as.data.frame(subset(dta, !is.na(dta[[x]]) & !is.na(dta[[y]]) & !is.na(dta[[z]]), select = c(x, y, z, weight)))
  tab <- dta_sub %>%
    group_by({{y}}) %>% 
    summarise(weighted_mean = weighted.mean({{x}}, {{weight}})) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
  return(head(tab))
}
```

It returns the following error when I run tab_mw_y_z(dta=df, x="f52_m", y="welle", z="s12g", weight="gewdef").

```
Error in `summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `weighted_mean = weighted.mean("f52_m", "gewdef")`.
i The error occurred in group 1: "welle" = "welle".
Caused by error in `x * w`:
! non-numeric argument to binary operator
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The code works as intended outside the function:

```
dta_sub %>%
  group_by(welle) %>% 
  summarise(weighted_mean = weighted.mean(f52_m, gewdef)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

I'm sure it must be a small thing but I really can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You supply `x` as string. Which works in `subset()` as `dta[[x]]`, but which doesn’t work with curly braces `{{x}}`.

Comment: PS: I forgot to add the reproducible sample: 

dftest <- as.data.frame(cbind(f52_m = sample(x = 1:10, size = 20, replace = TRUE),
                        welle = sample(x = 1:6, size = 20, replace = TRUE),
                        s12g = rep(c(101, 102, 103), 20),
                        gewdef = runif(n=20, min = 0, max = 1)))

Comment: In this regard your function and the statement at the bottom of your post are not the same.

Comment: @TimTeaFan I figured as much ;) How do you suggest I fix it?

Comment: Define `x_str <- rlang::englue("{{x}}")` and use that instead of `x`  in subset.

Comment: And then you would need to call the `x` argument of the function with a bare object name `f52_m`.

Comment: Due to this function being part of quite a big function I need to be able to use the quotation marks when entering the variables into the function.

Comment: Ok then instead of `{{x}}` use either `.data[[x]]` or alternatively `!! sym(x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.  The function below uses the curly brace fences throughout both selecting and subsetting the data and in the evaluation of the weighted mean.  In the first version of the function, you can submit the variable names without quotes.

```r
library(dplyr)
tab_mw_y_z <- function(dta, x, y, z, weight){
  dta_sub <- dta %>% 
    select({{x}}, {{y}}, {{z}}, {{weight}}) %>% 
    na.omit()
  tab <- dta_sub %>%
    group_by({{y}}) %>% 
    summarise(weighted_mean = weighted.mean({{x}}, {{weight}})) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
  return(head(tab))
}

data(mtcars)
set.seed(519)
mtcars$weight <- runif(nrow(mtcars), .5, 1.5)

tab_mw_y_z(mtcars, qsec, cyl, hp, weight)
#>   cyl weighted_mean
#> 1   4      19.34427
#> 2   6      17.88956
#> 3   8      16.87985
```

If you would rather submit the variable names in quotes, you could use the function below.

```r
tab_mw_y_z <- function(dta, x, y, z, weight){
  dta_sub <- dta %>% 
    select(all_of(c(x, y, z, weight))) %>% 
    na.omit()
  tab <- dta_sub %>%
    group_by(!!sym(y)) %>% 
    summarise(weighted_mean = weighted.mean(!!sym(x), !!sym(weight))) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
  return(head(tab))
}

tab_mw_y_z(mtcars, "qsec", "cyl", "hp", "weight")
#>   cyl weighted_mean
#> 1   4      19.34427
#> 2   6      17.88956
#> 3   8      16.87985
```

Finally, with @MrFlick's suggestion from the comments:

```r
tab_mw_y_z <- function(dta, x, y, z, weight){
  dta_sub <- dta %>% 
    select(all_of(c(x, y, z, weight))) %>% 
    na.omit()
  tab <- dta_sub %>%
    group_by(.data[[y]]) %>% 
    summarise(weighted_mean = weighted.mean(.data[[x]], .data[[weight]])) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
  return(head(tab))
}

tab_mw_y_z(mtcars, "qsec", "cyl", "hp", "weight")
#>   cyl weighted_mean
#> 1   4      19.34427
#> 2   6      17.88956
#> 3   8      16.87985
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. This still returns the same error for me because of the following: I need to submit the variables to the function with "" as in tab_mw_y_z(dta=df, x="f52_m", y="welle", z="s12g", weight="gewdef").
This is because the function is part of a larger function.

Comment: @R.Isabel I added a separate version of the function that works with quoted variable names.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much! I had tried with sym(x) but I didn't know I had to add the !! 
This solves my issue. Thank you for your time and your help. Have a good one!

Comment: I believe the current recommendation is to use `.data[[y]]` rather than `!!sym(y)` when using character values.

Comment: Thanks, @MrFlick.  Things seem to evolve pretty quickly in this space.  I sometimes have a hard time keeping up with what exactly the recommendation is at any particular time.